# Getting wrong data value from array location during assignment

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, fibonacci

I'm doing a programming exercise where I have to implement the fibonacci sequence using a loop (not recursive).

While it's not perfect by any means, the main issue I have is with my algorithm.

Because the variable intBuffer is assigned a pointer, it changes as the value of `intArray[1]` changes, rather than retain the previous value, before assigning it to memory location `intArray[0]`.

I have tried using the `*` prefix to get a data value rather than a memory location, but this produced an error:

> error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')

Code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int intArray[1];
    int intRounds, intIndex, intBuffer;
    printf("How many iterations would you like me to calculate? \n");
    scanf("%d", &intRounds);

    intArray[1] = 1;
    intArray[0] = 0;

    for (intIndex = 0; intIndex <= (intRounds - 1); intIndex++)
    {
        intBuffer = intArray[1];
        intArray[1] = intArray[1] + intArray[0];
        intArray[0] = intBuffer;
        printf("Iteration %d: %d \n", (intIndex + 1), intArray[1]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post the code which has problem.

Comment: You want `int intArray[2]`. The rule is simple: an array of `N` elements is indexed from `0` to `N-1`. If you need `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`, `arr` needs to be 2 elements long.

Answer (score 3):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour, as you're defining `intArray` to have only one element and then you're trying to access 2nd element, by

```
 intArray[1] = 1;
```

`C` uses 0 based indexing for arrays, so for a one-element array, index `1` is an access beyond allocated memory and will  invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, regarding the logic, inside the `for`  loop, you're constantly overwriting the value at `intArray[i]`.

You should

1. Define an array large enough to hold all the values of the series length. You can make use of a pointer and [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for dynamic memory allocation, or [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (if supported).
2. Use the loop counter `intIndex` to index the target element in each iteration.